# How do I do CRUD operations on a MySQL database using python via a class implementation?

Tags: python, mysql, attributeerror, mysql-connector-python

I have a MySQL database running on local machine, and I am able to read and write using MySQLConnector library.

I have standalone read and write methods which are working just fine, I just wanted to clean things up a bit and wanted to have all my CRUD operations be part of some class DatabaseOperations. I keep on getting a variety of errors however which I haven't found answers to, so I was hoping I could find further information here on what I need to do to make my class based CRUD operations work.

Below is a method to write to some table, I have a similar db_read method that is exactly the same thing except with a different SQL command

```
def db_write():
    local_ip = '192.168.120.191'  # LOCAL MACHINE SERVER RUNNING ON
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)  # SOCK_DGRAM refers to UDP
    s.connect((local_ip, 80))

    client_ip = str(s.getsockname()[0])
    print(client_ip)
    db_connection = mysql.connector.connect(
            host="localhost",
            user="localuser",
            password="localpass",
            database="Testing"
        )
    db_cursor = db_connection.cursor()
    db_cursor.execute(
        f"INSERT INTO receiving (client_ip, client_message) VALUES( '{client_ip}', '{globalResultsList[0]}');"
    )
    db_connection.commit()
    db_cursor.close()
```

And here is an attempt at a class based implementation

```
class DatabaseOperations:
    def __init__(self):
        self.local_ip = '192.168.120.191'  # LOCAL MACHINE SERVER RUNNING ON
        self.s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)  # SOCK_DGRAM refers to UDP
        self.s.connect((self.local_ip, 80))
        self.db_connection = mysql.connector.connect(
            host="localhost",
            user="localuser",
            password="localpass",
            database="Testing"
        )

    def readFromDatabase(self):
        db_cursor = self.db_connection
        db_cursor.execute(
            f"select * from receiving;"
        )
        db_result = db_cursor.fetchall()
        print(db_result)
```

Further down below in that class I have the writeToDatabase method which just has different SQL command.

The error I have been getting the most is:

```
AttributeError: 'MySQLConnection' object has no attribute 'execute'
```

Thanks!

Comment: `db_cursor = self.db_connection` is wrong, it should be `db_cursor = self.db_connection.cursor()` just like in `db_write()`.

Answer (score 2):

I do see you are defining `db_cursor = self.db_connection` inside the `readFromDatabase()` class method, so you are attempting to use a connection object as a cursor object (you are getting the error because of it when running `db_cursor.execute(...)`).

Based on your code the right definition would be:

```py
# reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlconnection-cursor.html
db_cursor = self.db_connection.cursor()
```

Eventually, you need to close the cursor, I suggest having a look at the [mysql-connector-python documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-reference.html) to learn how you can open/close a cursor, create different cursor types, and learn more about the API in general.